# Why my delegate method never gets called?

Tags: ios, delegates, http-post

I was following these question and tutorials:

- [fetching data with get post methods](http://kemal.co/index.php/2012/02/fetching-data-with-getpost-methods-by-using-nsurlconnection/)
- [sending http get and post from cocoa](http://www.deusty.com/2006/11/sending-http-get-and-post-from-cocoa.html)
- [nsurlconnection basics for beginners](http://yuvarajmanickam.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/nsurlconnection-basics-for-ios-beginners/)
- [sending an http post request on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-an-http-post-request-on-ios)
- [how to hanlde multiple delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474526/how-to-handle-multiple-delegates)

But I am still missing something. My delegate method

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

gets called all the time, takes a little bit time and I guess its because of internet speed, but the method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
```

never gets called. What am I missing? Please help me.

My code:

```
-(void)loadDataBase{
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"advnr=123"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://thewebsite.abc/interface.php"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    //return @"";
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSURLConnection delegates

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {
    NSLog(@"Success"); // never gets executed
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"didFinished");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"FAILED");
}
```

Comment: This delegate method is only call when the webservice return data, are you sure that you'r post request returns data other than a 200 http header ?

Comment: yes, when I test it with my html test form I always get data that I need on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that there is truly no data being returned (either because of some web service error or incorrectly prepared request).

You can use [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) to observe the request and the response to confirm this, if you'd like. BTW, Charles, or any tool like this, is a useful weapon to add to your arsenal, as it greatly simplifies diagnosing HTTP problems, isolating network related issues from client-side programming issues.

Regardless, if you get these sorts of errors, you will often get a non-200 `statusCode` returned by the server. See [list of HTTP status codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10).

You can verify this by also implementing `didReceiveResponse` and inspect the header of the response:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response {
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
        int statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
        if (statusCode != 200) {
            NSLog(@"Status code = %ld; response = %@", (long)statusCode, response);

            // handle this error however you'd like
        }
    }

    // temporarily, you might even want to log the whole `response` regardless of the status code
    NSLog(@"%s: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, response);
}
```

Comment: I get `{ status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Sun, 12 Oct 2014 19:21:08 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.22";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.26";
} }` but I can't understand why... If I use html test form I always get my data..

Comment: That's encouraging. We want to see `200`. So the next question is whether the server truly returned nothing or not. This is where Charles becomes invaluable.

Comment: Content length is 0... that means I get no data,right?

Comment: Yep. Which makes me suspect a server problem or API problem.

Comment: Very strange... I always get data when im using html test form. Thanks for help.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes there are cookies involved. Or a field name has been misspelled. Or some hidden field that the server is looking for. In some cases, the web service is actually looking for the `User-Agent` header field (to confirm it's a web browser). Hard to say without seeing HTML. Did I mention that Charles is useful here (watch web browser request vs app request and compare)? lol. Good luck!